# I want to know how to pass ShellContent arguments at Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am developing on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019.
I want to know how to pass `ShellContent` arguments.
I am building an application with Xamarin.Forms (v5.0.0.2012) and Xamarin.Essentials (v1.6.1).

We are using the tab page template. In `AppShell.xaml`, at the tab bar, I want to pass an argument to the same page (`ItemsViewModel`).
Specifically.

- `RegistDate` to pass the character "RegistDate" to `ItemsPage`.
- `ExecuteDate` passes the character "ExecuteDate" to the `ItemsPage`.
- `Stars` passes the word "Stars" to the `ItemsPage`.

AppShell.xaml

```
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="BrowseByRegistDate" Icon="registrationicon.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="ExecuteDate" Icon="execute.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="SortByStars" Icon="star.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

In the `ItemsPageViewModel`, add args to the constructor.

```
public ItemsViewModel(string args ="")
{
    Title = "Browse "+ args;
    // Processing for each args below.
}
```

What do I need to add to which xaml file or C# file?

The goal of this process is as follows.
(1)BrowseByRegistDate sorts and displays the file list in order of registration date.
(2)ExecuteDate sorts and displays the file list in order of execution date.
(3) SortByStars sorts and displays the list of files in order of importance.

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

public ItemsViewModel(string args)
{
    Title = "Browse "+args;
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    if (args=="RegistDate")
        Items.SortByRegistDate();
    else if (args=="ExecuteDate")
        Items.SortByExecuteDate();
    else if (args=="Stars")
        Items.SortByStars();
SortByStars(); }
```

For example, here's the code I tried; Button Clicked does not work.

```
<ShellContent Title="★★★" Icon="img_464925.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" >
    <Button Text="SortByStars" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnSortByStarsClicked" />
</ShellContent>
```

Comment: it is not clear enough, what is the end goal of passing the parameter ?

Comment: You could binding the data to ViewModel so that you can access it in VM directly .

Comment: Thank you comment Cfun. I added the end goal.

Comment: Thank you comment Lucas Zhang. I binding ItemsView(.xaml) to ItemsViewModel. But this ShellContent exist in AppShell Class. So I can't access AppShell ShellContent in ItemsViewModel.